# Filtering rows from a dataframe and creating a new one with only similar values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to take a dataframe of "patient' and 'drug" data and  create a new data frame with only patients that have used both drugs.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['1001', 'A'], ['1001', 'B'], ['1002', 'A'], ['1003', 'B'], ['1004', 'A'], ['1004', 'B']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['patient', 'drug'])



patient drug
1001    A
1001    B
1002    A
1003    B
1004    A
1004    B
```

I started by filtering and creating 2 separate dataframes on the drug value.

```
df1 =df.loc[(df['drug'] == 'A')]
df2 =df.loc[(df['drug'] == 'B')]
```

My issue is that I want to combine these 2 dataframes but only keep the rows that have ths same patients in both dataframes. I tried to use .concat but it did't give me what I wanted, I just combined the dataframe back together.

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], join="inner")
```

This is what I want the output to look like

```
 patient drug
 1001    A
 1001    B
 1004    A
 1004    B
```

I know I'm probably just missing an easy parameter but I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby`:

```
>>> df.loc[df.groupby("patient")["drug"].transform("nunique")==2]
  patient drug
0    1001    A
1    1001    B
4    1004    A
5    1004    B
```

Comment: Make sure to drop duplicates first. If there is another row with `['1001', 'A']` this wont work.

Comment: @It_is_Chris - Excellent suggestion. Edited :)

Comment: I assumed no duplicates based on the example but you can never be too sure. Either way it is a good answer. +1 from me.

Comment: I think using `nunique` in the transform might be better.

Comment: Yes, that is certainly a better approach than `drop_duplicates`. Never even crossed my mind

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the list of patients appear in both `df1` and `df2` by inner merge with [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on the 2 dfs on column `patient`.  Then, use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to filter the patients in the original `df`, as follows:

```
df.loc[df['patient'].isin(df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='patient')['patient'])]
```

**Result:**

```
  patient drug
0    1001    A
1    1001    B
4    1004    A
5    1004    B
```

### Additional Test Case

If, in case the original `df` has a 3rd drug other than 'A' and 'B', e.g.

**Input**

```
data = {'patient': [1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1004, 1004],
        'drug': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

   patient drug
0     1001    A
1     1001    B
2     1001    C
3     1002    A
4     1003    B
5     1004    A
6     1004    B
7     1004    C
```

**Output**

```
df1 =df.loc[(df['drug'] == 'A')]
df2 =df.loc[(df['drug'] == 'B')]

df.loc[df['patient'].isin(df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='patient')['patient'])]

   patient drug
0     1001    A
1     1001    B
2     1001    C
5     1004    A
6     1004    B
7     1004    C
```

Here, we also display rows with the 3rd drug `'C'` since we are still fufilling the requirement of

> only keep the rows that have the same patients in both dataframes.

(though with extra drugs but still the same set of patients).

If, in this case, we want a clean output to display the entries with only drug 'A' and 'B', we can use:

```
df_A_B = df1.append(df2).sort_values(['patient', 'drug'])

df_A_B.loc[df_A_B['patient'].isin(df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='patient')['patient'])]
```

**Result:**

```
    patient drug
0     1001    A
1     1001    B
5     1004    A
6     1004    B
```